# Design pattern for complex game algorithms

Tags: php, design-patterns, game-engine

This is a follow-up to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12029517/correcting-a-large-disadvantage-to-the-decorator-pattern). The context is the same, so skimming that one might be useful. I've been brainstorming this for days and gotten nowhere so I'm giving up and coming here.

I'm wondering what design patterns come into play when creating a system like the one I described there. Lets say I have a combat algorithm, that can have any number of combatants on each side. First we figure out who attacks whom, and then it's executed.

The tricky part is that there are a lot of additional behaviors that could be added, and they could be somewhat arbitrary. Think of them like "passive skills". There can also be behaviors like getting stat gains when you hit your target, but only in some types of combat.

My previous question shows how Decorator failed. An answer suggested the Strategy pattern, but I'm not eager to write a dozen different types of strategy, and then several concrete classes for each of those. Even then, I would still have to violate the Open Closed principle if I needed a brand new behavior that was totally unlike anything I had already. There will also be cases where I need to combine multiple strategies at a time, which could lead to decorated-strategies or composite-strategies. An example would be that when you take damage, you might 1. have an ability that cuts damage in half, 2. have an item equipped that further reduces damage, 3. return some damage to your attacker, and 4. gain some stat points.

So what would an experienced architect do here? Plenty of games have these systems implemented so I'm curious about what pattern or combination of patterns work well here.

*I don't want to post a huge wall of code, so if there's any specific part of my system you would like to see just ask in a comment.*

Answer (score 0):

This is a big question the requires knowledge of your game mechanics.  But I'll start with this recommondation.  A first step is to make sure you have a well-define and documented order of operation, and then convert that into a frameowkr or template for your combat resolution algorithm.  For example:

> An example would be that when you take damage, you might 1. have an
>   ability that cuts damage in half, 2. have an item equipped that
>   further reduces damage, 3. return some damage to your attacker, and 4.
>   gain some stat points.

What if #3 (damage reflection) happens first, then #4 (you gain stats, perhaps even defens pts), then #1 and #2.  In this case the defender has maximized the damage retrned and potentiall maximized his defense as well.

You listed these steps in a particular order, but **why**?  You must define your rules such that you know when each step if applied (attack and defender).  Only then can you create a system to reolve the combat.  For example:

1. Start with base damage
2. Apply attacker effects that are attack-triggered
3. Apply defender effects that are attack-triggered
4. Apply all attacker's damage-increasing innate abilities
5. Apply all attacker's damage-increasing equipment abilities
6. Apply all defender's armor-increasing innate abilities
7. Apply all defender's armor-increasing equipment abilities
8. Apply attacker effects that are defense-triggered
9. Apply defender effects that are defense-triggered
10. Take damage
11. Apply attacker effects that are damage-triggered
12. Apply defender effects that are damage-triggered

This is from the hip, I don't know your rule system.

Once you have this, consider modeling a Combat to include a Source, Target, a (starting) Damage, a list AttackEffects, and a list of DefenseEffects.  These effects should be coded as a Template (Template Method pattern) with OnAttack(), OnApplyInnate(), OnApplyEquipment(), OnDamaged() etc.  Then you can iterate the effects in the various phases of combat reolution, giving each the opportunity to apply its effect at the appropriate time.

Comment: To sum up, don't put the damage resolution code in the Combatant.  Relocate it to a Combat class, which contains the required information to resolve it, including a list of CombatEffects contributed by the attacker and defender.  Generically interate the effects in a manner and order controlled by your rule system, allowing each to modify the damage or otherwsie creaete side-effects (like damage reflection).  A final "ApplyDamage" method should deduct life points and execute any side-effects.